# MPMoviePlayerController rewind button

Tags: ios

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play full screen streaming and progressive videos. For streaming videos, instead of a rewind to the beginning button, there is a rewind 30 seconds button.

[image: streaming]
[image: progressive]

What I would really like to do is have the 30 second button appear for both progressive and streaming videos. How to do this without building a custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPMoviePlayerController is a fairly high-level object that doesn't provide very many customization points.  Unfortunately if you want to change the UI in this way you are pretty much on the road to a custom control.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. I might add that entirely recreating the existing UI and only differing from the original in this single point is a rather big bite to swallow. There is a lot of functionality one may not see immediately.

Comment: I completely agree.  However, the other solution I've seen of digging into the view hierarchy to make changes is also not recommended.  When (not if) Apple changes the MPMoviePlayerController's view hierarchy, you're app is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It's determine by the video' format.

- url_1: **(.mov)** http://download-ipa.qiniudn.com/IMG_1911.MOV
- url_2:**(.m3u8)** 
   http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

Add two url in same code,but when play...

So if you want make MPMoviePlayerController player with rewind buttton you must translate video format or customed video player.

**- url_1 :**------------------------------------------------------------ **- url_2 :**

[image] [image]