# How to show a "jump back" control in AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I just replaced the deprecated `MPMoviePlayerViewController` with `AVPlayerViewController` in my current project. It works like a charm except for one little thing:

I noticed that the useful "jump back" control that was automatically displayed in `MPMoviePlayerViewController`:

[image: Controls in MPMoviePlayerViewController]

is simply gone in `AVPlayerViewController`:

[image: Controls in AVPlayerViewController]

Is there any way to get it back?

And if not: Why did Apple remove it?

Comment: I think you need to implement it yourself. Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20430965/22147

Comment: Not worth it in my opinion because as stated in the comments of the post you linked this would mean manually rebuilding the `AVPlayerViewController` from scratch. I thought there might be an easier way like setting a boolean or something. Thanks for the link!